# Is there a command-line tool that copies visual studio's C++ auto-ident style?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, indentation

I want to enforce the indentation rules from our style guide upon commit to our linux-hosted subversion repository.
Our indentation rules are what-ever is allowed by the visual studio 2010 "edit->advanced->format Selection" command with indentation set to 2 spaces. (This has been the result of a team negotiation - If I insist on a more invasive style, the whole policy will loose support from the team)

So I need a unix tool or script that can replicate the same indentation rules that visual studio uses. I can then call that from the subveriion pre-commit hook, and block the commit if the tool changes the committed file at all.

I've tried looking at [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net), [bcpp](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/bcpp.html), and [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), and I can't make any of them produce identical output to visual studio. astyle gave the closest results, but insists an indenting line continuations by more than one additional indent.

Edit in response to the comments: Our developers regularly setup new computers and occasionally (several times a year) forget to set the per-developer VS indent options correctly. This isn't spotted until well after the commit at which point significant amounts of code need to be remediated. We already check for tabs which has caught the majority of these mistakes. I've been asked by the developers to look for a better solution to help them avoid mistakes.

Comment: Yikes.  Sounds a bit totalitarian.  Sorry I can't help with that, but have you thought of something a bit simpler?  *ie* scanning the file and checking that all indents are multiples of two and that the indent level of each successive line never changes by more than one.

Comment: There are different ways of addressing the core issue. The simplest would be defining the rules for the formatting and setting the VS configuration to follow that pattern. On the opposite end, trust the developers and don't enforce style on commit hooks, but rather as part of the code review. If a file is incorrectly indented, raise a ticket and have the programmer fix it (`svn annotate` can be used to pinpoint who did the change). You could also use `astyle` and then do a diff with a bit of context, post processing the result to determine whether the difference is just on the expected case.

Comment: Better not indent at all. It saves even more space and makes code less readable than what you've already achieved with 2 spaces. <Picard facepalm>

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for consistent team settings and just found [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/). A number of plugins exist that you install in your preferred editor that read the settings which are committed in the source code repository.